# Throw Bytes OverFlow

Tags: c#

I was learning to work with files in C# and I wanted to write `Program.cs` plus an other statement to a file.
but I received an error that says to me `ThrowBytesOverFlow` .

[image]

I think that I must convert everything that I want to write to a `char` array and then encoding it to `bytes`.

I dont know how can I solve this!

```
FileStream afile = new FileStream(@"..\..\Program.cs", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] byteData = new byte[afile.Length];
        char[] charData = new char[afile.Length];
        afile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        afile.Read(byteData, 0, (int)afile.Length);
        Decoder d = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        d.GetChars(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, charData, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(charData);
        afile.Close();

        byte[] bdata;
        char[] cdata;
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"..\..\My file.txt", FileMode.Create);
        cdata = "Testing Text!\n".ToCharArray();
        bdata = new byte[cdata.Length];            
        Encoder e = Encoding.UTF8.GetEncoder();
        e.GetBytes(cdata, 0,cdata.Length, bdata, 0, true);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.Write(bdata, 0, bdata.Length);

        byte[] bydata = new byte[charData.Length];
        e.GetBytes(charData, 0, charData.Length, bydata, 0, true);
        stream.Write(bydata, 0, bydata.Length);
        stream.Close();
```

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: Bytes and characters have different lengths.  Use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)`

Comment: ThrowBytesOverflow sounds like a competitor web site for StackOverflow.  It is not a .NET exception.

Comment: the actual message is on the console and its very long how can i show u that?

Comment: @user1889122 Edit your question and post the message and stack trace.

Comment: Looks like Slaks has your main answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are deliberately working at the level of bytes and encodings in order to learn more about them. If so, then this answer will not be helpful. However, the following code should do what you are aiming for:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\Program.cs");
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\My file.txt"))
{
    file.WriteLine("Testing Text!");
    file.Write(contents);
}
```

The "using" statement, if you are not familiar with it, automatically closes the file we are writing to when the program gets to the end of the block. It is equivalent to writing:

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\My file.txt"))
file.WriteLine("Testing Text!");
file.Write(contents);
file.Close();
```

except that if an exception is thrown inside the using block then the file will still get closed.